# extracting color code on button click-android

Tags: android, button

Is there any way to extract the color code (background color) of a button on clicking it and using it in the curresponding java code?

The purpose is to get same identifier on clicking same colored buttons in different activities.

Comment: Which color are you trying to identify in particular? Text color, background, another color all together?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCurrentTextColor()`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      int color = button.getCurrentTextColor();
   }
});
```

Comment: I would like to get the background color. To be specific.